# JPA Composite Key with @EmbeddedId more than 3 relations

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Can I use @EmbeddedId in case more than 3 relations with composite key ?

**relation**
parent -> child -> grandchild -> great-grandchild

**parent**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="mig_club_info")

public class MigGolfClub {
    @Id @Column(name = "club_id")
    private String club_id;
}
```

**child**

```
@Embeddable
public class MigCourseId implements Serializable{
    private String club_id;
    private String course_id;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="mig_course_info")
public class MigCourse {
    @EmbeddedId
    private MigCourseId migCourseId;

    @MapsId("club_id")
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "club_id")   
    private MigGolfClub migGolfClub;
}
```

**grandchild**

```
@Embeddable
public class MigHoleId implements Serializable{
    private MigCourseId migCourseId;
    private int hole_num;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="mig_hole_info")
public class MigHole {
    @EmbeddedId
    private MigHoleId migHoleId;

    @MapsId("migCourseId")
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns( {
        @JoinColumn(name="club_id"),
        @JoinColumn(name="course_id")
    })  
    private  MigCourse migCourse;
}
```

**great-grandchild**

```
@Embeddable
public class MigTeeId implements Serializable{
    private MigHoleId migHoleId;
    private String t_name;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="mig_tee_info")
public class MigTee {
    @EmbeddedId
    private MigTeeId migTeeId;

    @MapsId("migHoleId")
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns( {
        @JoinColumn(name="club_id"),
        @JoinColumn(name="course_id"),
        @JoinColumn(name="hole_num")
    })  
    private  MigHole migHole;
}
```

I tested and got a error message

```
nested exception is org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: Unexpected nested component on the referenced entity when mapping a @MapsId: xxx.xxx.xxx.MigHole"
```

I succeeded with grandchild (2-relations) , but I failed with greate-grandchild (3-relations)

Can't I use @EmbeddedId in case more than 3 relations with composite key?? --;;

Comment: I solved this problem by upgrading hibernate version (5.1.0)